# jQuery indexOf function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a location of an element in a jQuery set.

**[Here's what I tried so far.](http://jsfiddle.net/xz9dW/)**

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$('ul').find('a').indexOf('.active');
```

And get the location of the `.active` in the set of `a`'s.

Is there something like an `indexOf()` function for jQuery? The `index()` method doesn't work

Comment: @gdoron the output is expected to be 2 (it's the 3rd `a` element)

Comment: @tobyodavies. [there is an helpful overload](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10406578/601179).

Comment: @gdoron I know, having posted an answer using exactly that function over 30 minutes ago.

Comment: @tobyodavies. That's weird... I'm sure I looked and didn't see it. ???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you pass a jQuery set (`$searchFor`) as an argument to the `index` method of another jQuery set (`$searchIn`) i.e.

```
$searchIn.index($searchFor)
```

it will return the index of `$searchFor` in the set `$searchIn`

In your example:

```
$('ul a').index($('ul a.active'));
```

​

Comment: Note: `$('ul a')` is equivalent to `$('ul').find('a')`

Comment: @Alp. [This is even faster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10406578/601179) as it doesn't need to query the DOM twice.

Comment: @gdoron, yep, that was my original version, but I edited to simplify --- no point repeating all the same jQuery performance tricks if performance was never an issue and it's harder to read (oneliners ftw)

Comment: **Performance is always an issue** whether it's specified in the question or not, it's an issue!

Comment: @gdoron "premature optimisation is the root of all evil" --- Donald Knuth. Also, if it's not a bottleneck it makes 0 difference, and if it makes it 1% harder to read it's usually not worth this kind of micro-optimisation even if it is.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give the `index` function a jQuery object:

```
var elements = $('ul a'); 
var index = elements.index(elements.filter('.active')); // 2

alert(index);
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/xz9dW/18/)
​

---

<s>There is no such function out of the box</s>, it can be done easily like this:

```
var index = -1;
$('ul a').each(function(i){
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
        index = i;
        return false;
    }
});

alert(index);
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/xz9dW/17/)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is sound, you're just grabbing the wrong element: http://jsfiddle.net/xz9dW/19/

```
var index = $('ul a.active').closest('li').index();
```

The `a` link has no `index()` value since it has no siblings; you have to grab the `li`

Comment: I want to be able to grab the index of the `a` in the set though

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by just asking for it in the [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

```
 $('ul a.active')
```

What do you mean by getting the location however?  Do you mean position? or URL?

If you would like to know which one you `click` on lets say.. You would use `$(this)` inside your event function.  Here is an example which returns the current position of the element you click on, if there are multiple with the `.active` class:

To get the position:

```
 $('ul a.active').click(function(){
     alert( $(this).position() );
 })
```

To get the URL location:

```
 $('ul a.active').click(function(){
     alert( $(this).attr('href') );
 })
```

Comment: location refers to index, you can't get a url or an element (in general) let alone one relative to a jQuery set. Also OP clearly knows how to use find, so `$('ul a.active')` clearly does nothing like what OP is asking for.

Comment: He's not asking for the `index` he's asking for `indexOf`, last i checked these were different.

Comment: How is "index" different from "indexOf"? I can't think of a single language that implements both on the same object type, and between languages they are synonymous. OP used the word "indexOf" not "index" because that is the name of the built in method in JS on arrays and strings. Also, because he is looking for the "indexOf" something means he is looking for _an index_ not a URL and not a position coordinate, this was my point.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what your point is? Using names of (effectively synonymous) methods to suggest a  contradiction in meaning of a plain English sentence doesn't make a lot of sense to me...

Comment: Why should `indexOf` on a `jQuery` collection return the URL? or it's position in px??? I'm with @tobyodavies!

Comment: I'm going by the Op's example, the way i understand it he is trying to find any element with the class may contain '.active', maybe i'm wrong.