# jquery index() with some specific selector...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, indexing, html-lists

I have a parent with li's, and given the pointer to a li, I want to get it's position as a child.

For this I used:

```
li.index()
```

Now... I have one more condition, it should find an index only among these children that have display:block property in css.

I tried it some other ways around but I was unable to solve it.
Do have any ideas?

**Edit**: PS: or, rather for these that do not have display:none property.

**EDIT 2**: Well I these all require the reference to parent or specific ids, but what if have only a pointer to a li, for example:

```
<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
<li>Bar</li>
<li>Fiz</li>
<li>Buz</li>
</ul>

li=$('li:nth-child(n)');
```

now, let's suppose I know only one variable, and I want it's index among these that don't have css display: none propery...

**Solved** This is what did it:

```
li.add(li.siblings()).filter(':visible').index( li );
```

Thanks for helping me out with great ideas and different approach. :)

Comment: Have you tried `li.filter(":visible").index()` ?

Comment: not yet, give me a sec I will try it out.

Comment: No... - li.filter(":visible").index() never works.

Comment: Isn't this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/8nKCw/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery indexOf function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406300/jquery-indexof-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the following markup:

```
<ul>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li style="display:none">Fiz</li>
  <li>Buz</li>
</ul>
```

We can determine the (zero-based) index of the last `li` all visible list items:

```
// 2
$("li:last").index("li:visible");
```

If we were to remove the `:visible` selector, and ask for the index of the last among all:

```
// 3
$("li:last").index("li");
```

#### Update: Using a Variable

If you had a variable reference to a specific list item:

```
var lastItem = $("#parent li:last");
```

You could still get its index among visible children in the same container:

```
var index = $(lastItem).index("#parent li:visible");
```

#### Update 2: No Explicit Parent ID

```
var index = lastItem.parent().find("li").index( lastItem );
```

Comment: yeah, but I mean this requires both parent id, and list id with: last attached, but isn't there any way I can use something like this:
`var li= /*$ my li; */ li.index(li.parent())`... or something like that...

Comment: @user1125062 See "Update 2" in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all of them for a dozen of time. But now I seem to finally get the point of how it works. I didn't think of it to select the sibling before filtering, but now it works, and this is how I've put it :) li.add(li.siblings()).filter(':visible').index( li )

Comment: THanks for helping with different approaches, it has helped me to understand how it works =)

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS ANS

```
   var listItem = document.getElementById('bar');
   alert('Index: ' + $('li').index(listItem));
```

fiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/VqeHW/

Answer (score 0):

Give your display:none elements a class, then use the .class selector:

```
$('#theList .visible').each(function () {
  var index = $('#theList .visible').index(this);
});
```